# regular expression for special characters

Tags: regex, validation

I am using this regular expression for validating email address for example:

```
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

and now I want to write a validation expression for not using one special character, like ";" in my example...

P.S. I know how to do this in JavaScript with the `keyCode` function for example, but I need it as a simple regular expression...

Comment: What do you mean, a validation expression for not using like ";" in your example? The English doesn't have a clear parse. Do you mean you want a regex that forbids semicolon anywhere in a string, that you want to add that restriction to your long emailish thing, or something else?

Comment: Your regex is already not allowing semicolons anywhere in the string. Can you show some examples of what should and shouldn't be matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're looking for an entirely new regex that has nothing to do with your email regex, and that the only rule for this regex is: "Match any string that does not contain a semicolon."

This is easy. Use the following regex:

```
^[^;]*$
```

**Explanation:**

`^` matches the start of the string.

`[^;]*` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). As the first character inside brackets, the `^` takes on a new meaning as "anything but". So this expression means "Match a character unless it's a semicolon". The `*` allows any number of repetitions, including zero.

`$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: Dear Mr. Pietzcker ... thank you very much for your good and clear explanation...